# Error using non-boolean type in a case when statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I'm trying to write a function in SQL Server that checks if a tuple exists in one of my tables or not. if so, it returns `1` else it should return `0`.

This is what I have written:

```
create function allow_user_to_score
    (@user_id char(6), @app_id char(7))
returns smallint
as 
begin
    declare @result

    select @result = case 
                        when (@user_id, @app_id) in (select * from installed_app) 
                           then 1 
                           else 0
    from installed_app

    return (@result)
end
```

but I get this error and I don't know why:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: What does `(@user_id, @app_id) in ( ...)` even mean?  It's not even a valid format.

Comment: @Eric they are parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple errors on your code. I'm assuming that you have 2 columns in your installed_app table called user_id and app_id.

```
CREATE FUNCTION allow_user_to_score(
    @user_id char(6), 
    @app_id char(7)
)
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result smallint;

    SELECT @result = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                        FROM installed_app 
                                        WHERE user_id = @user_id 
                                        AND app_id = @app_id) 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 END;
    RETURN @result;
END
```

As mentioned by Sean, this can easily be converted to an inline table-valued function for a great boost in performance.

```
CREATE FUNCTION allow_user_to_score(
    @user_id char(6), 
    @app_id char(7)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT result = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                        FROM installed_app 
                                        WHERE user_id = @user_id 
                                        AND app_id = @app_id) 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to convert this scalar function into an inline table valued function. It would be more flexible and performant.

Comment: Totally agree with you @SeanLange, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   declare @result smallint
    select @result = sign(count(*)) from installed_app 
                     where userId=@userId and appId=@appId
    return (@result)
```

If you know there can only be 1 record (or 0), you can remove the sign() function

Comment: Using COUNT(*) is a horrible idea to validate existance of rows. This will create a problem as the table grows.

Comment: Depends on the indexes on the table and size of the table, but I agree count(1) would be better.

Comment: No, COUNT(*) and COUNT(1) or any variation that uses COUNT() is going to be problematic when the table grows. EXISTS() is a far better way to know if a table has rows or not.